# Evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, nested-radicals

Can we evaluate this?
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^{n^2}$$
I came up into this while I was thinking of some nested radical problem like:
$$\sqrt{7\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{7\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{7\dots}}}}}}}}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with Jacobi Elliptic functions, you will find that 
$$K = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^{n^2}
= \frac12\left( 1+\vartheta_3(0;\frac12)\right) \approx 1.56446841361
$$
There is no simpler expression for $K$.

Because the series for $K$ approaches rational numbers "quickly" it is likely that it is transcendental.  For example, the Fredholm number 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^{2^n}$$ has beeen proven to be transcendental.

Comment: $\vartheta_3(0,t)$ is known to be transcendental for algebraic $t$ with  $0 < t < 1$.  See [this Math Overflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55397/is-this-number-already-known-to-be-transcendental-is-there-a-survey-about-up-to).